# Was the number of votes for write in candidates for the 2020 presidential election ever released?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, data-sources

In the 2020 presidential election in the United States there were more than a thousand [write in candidates](https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_registered_2020_presidential_candidates) . But I never saw any reports on the votes they got.

Did the government ever release any official number? Do we know how many votes did they got?

Comment: Your source appears to show 1,212 registered with the FEC to run, not that there were that many write-in candidates. Bear in mind that it's not one federal government running an election, it's 50 state governments (and DC), all with their own rules.

Comment: @origimbo There were different state rules, that's true. Of all those candidates some were running only in some states and could not get votes on other states that's true. But even if they were running on one leg or with one hand tied behind their back they were still runnning and I would like to know how they did.

Comment: Then the most official route is to look at the relevant board of elections (etc.) pages (e.g. https://electionresults.dcboe.org/election_results/2020-General-Election, which doesn't seem to break down write ins). The best source I know of to find them quickly is https://www.thegreenpapers.com/G20/ but I'm sure there are better ones

Comment: @origimbo Your comment could be an answer. The second link has the best overview I saw for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of; the FEC’s [report](https://www.fec.gov/resources/cms-content/documents/2020presgeresults.pdf) of the official results of the 2020 presidential election gives an overall figure of 159,752 votes cast for write-in candidates. Unfortunately, their figures can only be based on those reported by the states themselves, and each state has a different way of reporting write-in votes. As I answered to a [similar question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/59694/what-is-the-us-national-average-of-write-in-votes-in-presidential-elections/59735):

> This question is tricky to provide an accurate answer to due to the inconsistencies between reporting of write-in votes. Some states report a total summary figure of 'write-in' votes, in some cases including write-in votes for registered candidates, and in some cases not. Other states provide figures for every separate candidate. As a result, consolidated reporting of write-in figures tends to depend on the methodology of the author.

For a complete breakdown of how many votes each write-in candidate got, you’ll need to look at the figures published by each individual state’s board of elections.

For example, [New York State’s results](https://www.elections.ny.gov/NYSBOE/elections/2020/General/2020President.xlsx) split out the votes cast for each individual write-in candidate, from 999 votes for Brian Carroll right down to 1 single vote for Richard Charles Montanye.

However, if we look at the NY row in the FEC’s report, the votes for Carroll have been split off into their own column, despite being write-in votes in New York, so the overall figure from the FEC is not the whole story.

Furthermore, the FEC’s report omits write-in figures for twelve states, including California, Louisiana, and New Jersey. As far as I know, no complete national breakdown of write-in votes for each candidate has been published.

Answer (score 0):

*Did the government ever release any official number?*

*Do we know how many votes did they got?*

The [FEC reports](https://www.fec.gov/resources/cms-content/documents/2020presgeresults.pdf#page=8) 159,752 write-in votes in the OFFICIAL 2020 PRESIDENTIAL GENERAL ELECTION RESULTS.

> Italics indicate Write-In Votes.

For some named candidates, a number in italics indicates write-in votes for that candidate within that state. Those votes are in addition to any numbers in the Write-In Votes column.